# How to disable or hide acrobat reader bookmarks panel in winform?

Tags: c#, acrobat

I'm showing PDF documents in my application using Acrobat ActiveX. I want to know is it possible to disable or hide Bookmarks(and Pages,Search,Comments,Attachments in left of panel) on PDF adobe reader when showing pdf?

Comment: Are you trying to toggle it while the Adobe Reader is already running? Is this for all instances of Adobe Reader? Or do others need to have Bookmarks showing?

Answer (score 4):

I hope that will help you.

```
// load pdf file
viewer.LoadFile(somePath);
// hide top toolbar
viewer.setShowToolbar(false);
// hide navigation bar
viewer.setPageMode("none");
```

'viewer' is ActiveX control from Adobe Reader (AcroPDFLib).

Comment: Thank's, but this still display that. I can't hide it!

Answer (score 3):

the solution is to add "#toolbar=0" ending path file, like this

```
axAcroPdf1.scr="c:/mifile.pdf"+"#toolbar=0"
```

Also, you can add other properties seperating with "&"

Comment: Unbelievable, it works. I searched and tried many ways, but not success. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I searched a lot for an answer to this one, and the best I could find is explained in this post : 
[NorthCode forum post](http://www.northcode.com/forums/showthread.php?t=9577)

Basically, it seems that you can only change the PageMode with this command, but not control the visibility of the panel.  This must be done within the interface.  It says that the value is remembered if you hide it manually, so in theory it would be hidden when you open the viewer again, but I couldn't make it work.

I finally gave up trying to hide it...